# Internet explorer does not show the login form of a website

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I'm using IE 11.1.17133.0 in windows 10 x64
When I try to open https://olymptrade.com/platform it doesn't show the login form.
but it works fine in chrome or...
how can I solve this?

Comment: Does it work in Edge?

Comment: Yes, it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it on my system (Windows 10 v1809 Enterprise x64), using Internet Explorer 11 and I'm only getting a message saying "You must log in to continue", but with no login form. It's possible that the website doesn't support Internet Explorer 11.

Also, to answer @Ramhound's question, the website works properly in Microsoft Edge (I can see the login form).

Comment: So is there any solution for that?

Comment: If the website doesn't support Internet Explorer 11, it isn't something you can fix on your site. The website owner needs to add/enable IE 11 compatibility. You should start by sending them an email and ask if IE is supported and tell them about the issue you're experiencing when you're trying to use it to browse their site.

Comment: No problem Meqdad, you're welcome!